# DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges not dropping the database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

The DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initialisation strategy no longer works in MVC5 with ASP.NET identity.
I'm getting the following error:

The model backing the 'BaseModelContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.

What do I do if for now I don't want to use migrations? Shouldn't the fact that I've TOLD it to drop the database that it should then go and do it?

Comment: I've had similar issues with EF in the past - I've just dropped the db through normal SQL instead and proceeded from there

Comment: Strange, could this be a bug within EF then?